# Tab widgets in jquery not showing at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am currently working on a web form and my jquery tabs are not showing when i run the page.I included this inside the header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
} );
</script>
```

and this inside the body:

```
div id="tabs">
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <div id="tabs-1">
      <p>...</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="tabs-2">
      <p>,,,</p>
  </div>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Next</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Next2</a></li>
  </ul>

 </div>
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing adding the base jquery-ui theme for your page to have the default styling. Just add the following line.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

Your full page would look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
} );
</script>

<div id="tabs">
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <div id="tabs-1">
      <p>...</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="tabs-2">
      <p>,,,</p>
  </div>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Next</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Next2</a></li>
  </ul>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You css file isn't pointing to anything. You need to use one of the jQuery UI themes. The snippet below uses a CDN for the jQuery UI Excite Bike theme:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
} );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/excite-bike/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Next</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Next2</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="tabs-1">
    <div>
      <p>Content for tab 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="tabs-2">
      <p>Content for tab 2</p>
  </div>


 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two "tabs-1" IDs. You do not need the second div inside the first div with id of "tabs-1".